# MySQL Syntax Error on Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

I cannot get this trigger code to compile on MySQL 5.3:

```
CREATE TRIGGER crmenq_bur 
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON crmenquiries
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (    NEW.feedback = OLD.feedback 
       AND NEW.notes = OLD.notes
       AND NEW.estatus = OLD.estatus )
   THEN
      SET NEW.update_type = 'NN';
   ELSE
      SET NEW.update_type = 'SEN';
      SET new.last_update2 = now();
   END IF;
   CASE 
      WHEN NEW.estatus != OLD.estatus AND NEW.estatus = 'FP3' THEN
         SET NEW.uid_follow_up = NEW.uid_last_update_by;
         SET NEW.follow_up_date = DATE_ADD ( date(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH );
      WHEN NEW.estatus != OLD.estatus AND NEW.estatus = 'FP6' THEN
         SET NEW.uid_follow_up = NEW.uid_last_update_by;
         SET NEW.follow_up_date = DATE_ADD ( date(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH );
      WHEN NEW.estatus != OLD.estatus AND NEW.estatus = 'FP9' THEN
         SET NEW.uid_follow_up = NEW.uid_last_update_by;
         SET NEW.follow_up_date = DATE_ADD ( date(), INTERVAL 9 MONTH );
      WHEN NEW.estatus != OLD.estatus AND NEW.estatus = 'FP12' THEN
         SET NEW.uid_follow_up = NEW.uid_last_update_by;
         SET NEW.follow_up_date = DATE_ADD ( date(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH );
      WHEN NEW.estatus NOT IN ( 'FP3', 'FP6', 'FP9', 'FP12' ) THEN
         SET NEW.uid_follow_up = NULL;
         SET NEW.follow_up_date = NULL;
   END CASE;
END;
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), INTERVAL 3 MONTH ); WHEN NEW.estatus != OLD.estatus AND NEW.estatus = ' at line 18]
```

Initially I had nested IF but changed to CASE to see if that made any difference. The current form is not how I had it originally (nested IF to avoid repeating the same condition) but with each unsuccessful attempt the code was changed but nothing I have tried has worked.

The column/tables names are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error thrown is due to call on MySQL `date()` function. It was wrongly used.

I am not sure if your intention was to use *current* date.
If yes, you can use any of the following suggestions on all `date()` usages in your code.

> [***curdate()***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)      -- Return the current date
>   [***current_date()***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) -- Synonyms for `CURDATE()`
>   [***current_date***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date)   -- Synonyms for `CURDATE()`

**Example**:

```
mysql> select curdate(), current_date(), current_date;
+------------+----------------+--------------+
| curdate()  | current_date() | current_date |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
| 2014-07-01 | 2014-07-01     | 2014-07-01   |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
```

You can also use [***`date()`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function but it takes an input parameter of type `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp`.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select date( sysdate() ), date( now() ), date( curtime() ), date( curdate() );
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| date( sysdate() ) | date( now() ) | date( curtime() ) | date( curdate() ) |
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 2014-07-01        | 2014-07-01    | 2014-07-01        | 2014-07-01        |
+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

***Refer to documentation***:

- [***MySQL: Date and Time Functions***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but got the same, i.e. changed:

SET NEW.follow_up_date = DATE_ADD ( date(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH );

to:

SET NEW.follow_up_date = DATE_ADD ( curdate(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH );


But got the same, however I was then able to try a few other things out and eventually got this working:

SET NEW.follow_up_date =  ( date(now()) + INTERVAL 12 MONTH );

So thanks for the help.

Comment: Repeated error was not due to use of `curdate()`. I am not sure if you have changed all `date()` occurrences to `curdate()` in the code. If yes, it should have worked. And, you can also use `curdate() + interval ..` instead of `date(now()) + interval ..`

Answer (score 0):

Change the delimiter with something like `Delimiter $$` before you start, and end your trigger with the new delimiter. Change it back when you're done, like this:

```
Delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER crmenq_bur 
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON crmenquiries
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 /* Body of code here */
END $$
Delimiter ;
```

Comment: This is not correct. If the error was on `delimiter`, exception would have been thrown on line `SET NEW.update_type = 'NN';`